# Jquery event listeners not working on appended elements (and they should, shouldn't they?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using Jquery UI datepicker for my Rails application, and I want to trigger an event whenever someone clicks on the button for next month. It is not triggering anything though. My JQuery version is v1.12.4.

Here's a sample of my html code:

```
<input type='text' name='date_from' class="form-control date_picker" placeholder="Data de ida..." id='datetimepicker1' required/>
<div id="datepicker1" class="calendar"></div>
```

The HTML code for the datepicker is the default generated by JQuery UI.

So here is my javascript attempt:

```
  $('body').on('click','.ui-datepicker-next',function(e){
    console.log('Next/prev month')
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

It does nothing! It doesn't raise an error on the console, it doesn't print anything and it doesn't attach the click event to the elements with the `ui-datepicker-next` class.

If I copy and paste the following code in the console it works well for the current elements in the document.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-next').click(function(e){
    console.log('Next/prev month')
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It has never happened to me before, so I'm sorry if this question should be more detailed, but I really don't know what else I should mention here.

Edit:

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9484zzrL/

This is the best I could do so far to recreate the issue on jsfiddle.
If you click on a day of the selected month it is fine, but if you change the month it doesn't work anymore.

Edit 2:

I believe this recreates perfectly my problem. Simply the event is not triggered when I choose any date in the calendar.

https://jsfiddle.net/awhwr3uv/

Comment: Your `<input>` element does not have the class "ui-datepicker-next".

Comment: Can you recreate this in a snippet?

Comment: I don't see you even attaching the datepicker to the input. Like `$('#datepicker1').datepicker();`

Comment: My guess would be that at the time when your javascript code is run the element is not yet present. Please try to debug it with:

    ````console.log($('.ui-datepicker-next').length))````

If so, then use your event listener at document.ready function. Otherwise, please upload your full javascript file.

Comment: Sorry for the missing parts of the code. That's the best I could do to recreate on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8n85dgxt/

Comment: This one works better: https://jsfiddle.net/9484zzrL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

So I looked at your latest jFiddle. I wondered if you had tried to use something like this:

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
  firstDay: 1,
  onSelect: function(date) {
    console.log('Date Selected: ' + date);

    //Do some other cool stuff here

    $(this).hide();
  }
});

$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
  firstDay: 1,
  onSelect: function(date) {
    console.log('Date Selected: ' + date);

    //Do some other cool stuff here

    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

You can carry out everything you need to in the onSelect option that is in your jFiddle and it even passes you the date to the callback as an argument.

**Original**

Change this:

```
$('body').on('click','.ui-datepicker-next',function(e){
    console.log('Next/prev month')
    e.preventDefault();
    //setTimeout(date_picker_listener(),500)
});
```

To this:

```
$(document).on('click','.ui-datepicker-next',function(e){
    console.log('Next/prev month')
    e.preventDefault();
    //setTimeout(date_picker_listener(),500)
});
```

It works in your fiddle.

**Edit**

I wanted to explain my guess at why your code didn't work.

I think it is because jQuery already has a click listener attached to the body element for the class of the button. Because 2 click listeners are attached to the body for the same class of element, the first one the JavaScript engine reaches is the one that fires.

In effect when you attach a click listener to the body using the on method the JavaScript engine is constantly scanning the body for clicks and then checking if the click matched your selector. Because jQuery already has the click listener on the body for that selector your listener never received the event.

With that in mind by attaching your click listener to the document, you have an entirely new listener set up and the engine is now also scanning the document for clicks and seeing it matches your selector. Because yours is the only one listening on the document yours gets the event.

So I tested this by changing the listener from click to mouseover and sure enough it works.

```
$('body').on('mouseover','.ui-datepicker-next',function(e){
    console.log('Next/prev month')
    e.preventDefault();
    //setTimeout(date_picker_listener(),500)
});
```

I hope this helps. It's the best I can come up with as to why your code didn't work.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, it does solve the problem in my fiddle. Still the same approach didn't work in my application :( it seems I did not recreate the problem well. If you still want to give it a try, I'm pretty sure this one recreates my problem perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/awhwr3uv/  Choosing a date does not trigger anything and it should.

Comment: The console keeps logging this error when I click a date. GET https://nikkomsgchannel/e?001a0027005e005a0044003000660050005a0057002b00540…2d0050005f005e00100023005c0047002c000c0057005800280052005c005c005f0029005f

Comment: Hmmmm I can't see it. My browser is not logging anything meaningful... nor firebug is.

Comment: I will take another look in a few hours.

Comment: OK, took another look and edited my answer. I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Awesome suggestion! It seems we still don't know why that code wasn't working, but with your suggestion my code got smaller, more efficient and it is working fine!

Comment: Yes the code worked fine on the next month button but not when you selected a date. At least with the new answer you can make your code neater. Glad I could help!